# Any alternative to the out of band management virtual drives?

Tags: remote-access, optical-media, out-of-band-management

The out of band management systems include a lot features to admin the servers on remote. I'm only interested in alternatives to the virtual CD/DVD drives included with these systems.

I would like to install different OS regularly on one of the computers changing the CDs (iso images in this case) on remote. Is there any alternative to the expensive OOBM systems for my purpose?.

I use serial cables to connect to the console. The computers are old, so AMT or IPMI is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the BIOS supports [PXE (network) booting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) you can do that.